# streaming with flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I have a flash player which is streaming trough rtmp protocol. The player is working well locally except when I use it remotelly. It doesnt stream although the streaming address is fine. Also we recently changed from http to using https.

Could there be problem with https or what could be the problem, any ideas would be great

Comment: I would guess you are getting a security issue. Are you running a debug version of Flash player in your browser? This should help.

Comment: how to check if it is a debug version?

Comment: goto this url http://www.playerversion.com/ and it should say debug version or right click on the flash and it should show a 'debugger' option.

Comment: is this browser based? if not, you could consider publishing an AIR app, which bypasses a lot of Flashes security protocols, as it is meant to run desktop, not browser.

Comment: Yes it is browser based and it will stay browser based. We discovered that the firewall on server side is what was blocking the stream.  Do I have to add additionall AS3 code to bypass the firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the player gets hostname instead of the ip address for streaming so it was struggling for 20 secs to do that. Ok we found that the DNS wasn't resolving the url for streaming properly :) So use real ip address to stream instead of hostname